# Remote Desktop: PC (2 screens) --> Mac (1 screen)

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control

I have what I believe is a fringe case, but it would be cool to find a solution. I have a Windows machine that I would like to use to connect over my home network to a Mac laptop I have. This I can accomplish, but I would like to use both of the monitors on my PC (so its like my Mac is connected to both monitors natively).

For example, when I use my Windows Desktop (2 monitors) to connect to a Windows Laptop using Windows RDP, I get to use my laptop as if two monitors were connected to it (or even 3 if I have that many on my Desktop). I find this to be one of the nicer features that Windows RDP offers.

Is there anyway to accomplish this when performing remote control form Windows --> Mac? Tool that has this feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've probably discovered, you can't use Microsoft's RDC to connect to a Mac, even though you can use it from a Mac to connect to a PC.

VNC is your best bet, as it is built into the Mac & there is free for home use software available for other platforms, but I know of nothing that can make the Mac suddenly sprout a virtual extra monitor.

See http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/

Comment: As the question asker is already using his Mac from Windows (with a single monitor), I assume he's already using some VNC client...

Comment: I could have just written, "No, you can't do that."

Comment: If the Mac would have multiple screens, then by using specific ports (5901, 5902, ...) one could make VNC connect to a specific screen. Of course, that's not what's being asked (and it's horrible as it needs multiple VNC clients probably yielding mouse pointer madness, and will scale the remote screen's resolution to the local screen). But: I wouldn't be surprised if the question can be solved somehow...

Comment: I'm really not sure how you would even go about suggesting the concept to the remote machine that it suddenly has a second monitor attached, which it can only 'see' over its VNC 'broadcast'.